# Crear webhook endpoint Stripe con php

Tags: php7, stripe, endpoint, webhook

Necesito crear un endpoint para saber el estado de los vales de oxxo, ya que en base a esta información en mi base de datos modificaré cuando un vale ya se ha pagado o cuando ya haya vencido y no se pago. Estoy usando API de Stripe como pasarela de pago y estoy usando php.

He visto la documentación [Triggering actions with webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events#deploy-endpoint) pero la verdad no logro entender nada.

Como primer paso ya he creado el webhook endpoint, no sé si los eventos que agregue sean los correctos porque en la documentación no especifican cuales son los necesarios y cuales no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como segundo paso en el archivo `verifcar.php` puse el primer código de ejemplo que viene en la documentación.

**verificar.php**

```
<?php
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_API_KEY');

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a StripePaymentIntent
        handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);
        break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a StripePaymentMethod
        handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
        break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
}

http_response_code(200);
?>
```

Aquí es donde ya no se que más hacer, tengo que ejecutar obligatoriamente unos comandos en consola que viene en la documentación?? **Stripe** ejecutará el archivo `verificar.php` por la dirección url que especifique al crear el endpoint?? En el código que pongo de ejemplo en que línea obtengo los vales para poder saber el estado de cada uno y poder hacer la modificación en mi BD??

Espero que pudieran orientarme con esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Aquí es donde ya no se que más hacer, tengo que ejecutar obligatoriamente unos comandos en consola que viene en la documentación??

Claro, ahora debes generar un evento como si hubieras pagado en OXXO. Si utilizas los emails de prueba, puedes generar los eventos sin tener que ir a una tienda OXXO. Por ejemplo, si utilizas como email del cliente succeed_immediately@test.com , entonces stripe enviará un webhook a elastillar.com/verificar.php de manera immediata.

Más detalles acá: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/oxxo/accept-a-payment#test-integration

> En el código que pongo de ejemplo en que línea obtengo los vales para poder saber el estado de cada uno y poder hacer la modificación en mi BD??

Al crear el pago, deberías guardar el token del payment intent, el cual lo obtienes en el payload del webhook de esta forma:

```
$paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contiene un objeto StripePaymentIntent
$paymentIntent.id; // el ID del PaymentIntent que creaste inicialmente
```

Comment: Pero entonces debo o no debo ejecutar los comandos en consola que vienen en la documentación??

Comment: Por que primero he creado un vale oxxo y después accedía desde un navegador al archivo verificar.php para ver que resultados me arrojaba y lo único que me devolvía era el mensaje "Received unknown event type"

Comment: De hecho acabo de hacer una prueba usando el correo succeed_immediately@test.com y con mi API_KEY_TEST y marco el error: Call to undefined function handlePaymentIntentSucceeded

Comment: Esa función handlePaymentIntentSucceeded corresponde alguna librería de la api de stripe o es una función que yo tengo que declarar?

Comment: Es una función que tu declaras donde ejecutas la lógica que estimes necesaria (enviar una notificación al cliente, actualizar la base de datos, etc).